# Subprocess.communicate() returns char at a time rather than lines

Tags: python, subprocess

I am running Python 2.7.2 on Windows and trying to automate a number of command line tools using subprocess as follows:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(mip4 + " status", bufsize=1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
for line in stdout:
    print line
```

Rather than producing a full line of output, the print statement prints a single character followed by a newline.

However, if I do:

```
print p.communicate()
```

the full output is printed correctly.

I've tried all the bufsize options to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

If your aim to get `output` of the command , you should use `check_output`.

```
In [120]: for x in subprocess.check_output(["/bin/sh", "-c", "ls -   a"]).split('\n'):
                print x
        .....:     
        .....:     
        .
        ..
        cluster.py
        database1.py
```